# How can I solve this type of error of communication web?

Tags: python, web, communication

```
from Adafruit_IO import *
aio = Client('user','key' )

value = 42
aio.send('communicationWeb',value)
```

I have developed this program to send information to my cloud adafruit when I run it, I've got this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/communication_mqtt/v2d.py", line 5, in <module>
    aio.send('communicationWeb',value)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Adafruit_IO/client.py", line 167, in send_data
    return self.create_data(feed, payload)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Adafruit_IO/client.py", line 313, in create_data
    return Data.from_dict(self._post(path, data._asdict()))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Adafruit_IO/client.py", line 139, in _post
    self._handle_error(response)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Adafruit_IO/client.py", line 117, in _handle_error
    raise RequestError(response)
Adafruit_IO.errors.RequestError: Adafruit IO request failed: 404 Not Found - not found - API documentation can be found at https://io.adafruit.com/api/docs
```

Comment: The API has a 404 not found error.  There appears to be some problem internal to the API you are using.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it asks for customer support with third-party services that requires inside access, knowledge, or tools. [Such questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745). Instead, please direct your question to the technical support team for the relevant company or organization.